# What's the risk of running net.ipv4.route.flush

Tags: linux, aws, sysctl

I'm setting up a Linux box through AWS and I'm exploring `sysctl`.
When I run `ip route` I can see that there are already routes on the machine refering to `169.X.X.X` addresses.
**Questions**:

1. What does `systctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1` do?
2. Could `systctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1` mess up the default box/configuration needed in order for the AWS Linux instance to work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

1. It causes the kernel function `ipv4_sysctl_rtcache_flush()` to be called with parameter `1`.

However, that function expects to get a network specification (technically a `struct net *`) as a parameter, not just `1`. So most likely `sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1` does nothing at all, because `1` is not a valid parameter for it.

2. If the system was depending on dynamically-created routes (i.e. running `gated` or similar routing daemon), then a successful clearing of the route cache might cause a temporary disruption of network traffic. But as I said above, that does not seem like a valid syntax for the `net.ipv4.route.flush` so it is likely to do nothing at all.

The `net.ipv4.route.flush` sysctl is apparently what `ip route flush` would use (or would have used at some point, if a better interface was developed since then). The `ip-route(8)` man page says this:

> `ip route flush`
>
> flush routing tables
>
> this command flushes routes selected by some criteria.
>
> The arguments have the same syntax and semantics as the arguments of ip route show, but routing tables are not listed but purged. The only difference is the default action: `show` dumps all the IP main routing table but `flush` prints the helper page.

A quick experimentation in a test VM told me `ip route flush 1` would only remove a route to 1.0.0.0/32 from the main routing table, but `sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1` won't do even that. So apparently the sysctl requires some non-trivial syntax to have any effect. Looking at the kernel source code, it seems it would require a data structure as a parameter, so the `net.ipv4.route.flush` sysctl is not really usable from the command line without a tool like `ip route`.

---

If you are seeing routes to `169.254.0.0/16` on any activated network interface, that is part of the Bonjour/Zeroconf system that would provide link-local connectivity without any configuration requirements. If you want to get rid of them, RedHat-style network configuration files would do it with a `NOZEROCONF=yes` setting in either `/etc/sysconfig/network` or in the per-interface `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface name>` file; other distributions may have other ways to opt out of Zeroconf configuration.